# Update Google Prettify to get highlight support for Logtalk and Prolog code

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Recent versions of Google Prettify include highlight support for the Logtalk programming language, which can also be used for the Prolog programming language (Logtalk syntax subsumes Prolog syntax).

Comment: At this point, I'm pretty sure the usual SE mantra "we don't maintain Google Prettify" will be trotted out.

Comment: Does new syntax increase amount of code loaded in browser on every request?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I guess no response at all is worse.